# "Appearance" icon has vanished from "System Settings"

Tags: unity, desktop-background, appearance

I have been using **gnome-shell** for a few months. I was able to configure it using *"tweak tool"* and *"background"*.
Now I've just migrated to **Unity**, but *"Change Desktop Background"* (comes from right-click on desktop) launches *"System Settings"*. I'm not able to swap desktop wallpaper or change launcher icons' size, etc.
As you can see from [this picture](http://uploadtak.com/images/g3473_where_is_appearance.png), the "**Appearance**" icon has been removed from "*System Settings*". What's happened to my Ubuntu?

My OS:
Ubuntu 12.10;
Unity + gnome-shell;
latest updates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try installing these packages in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-signon
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-unity
```

That should bring it back.